# Neighbourhood of an element in a product space $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be the topological subspace $\left([0,\infty)\right)\times \mathbb{R}) \cup (\mathbb{R}\times \{0\})$ of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$

If $U$ is an open subset in $A$ and $(x,0)\in U$, why does there exist $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\times\{0\}\subseteq U$

I know that $(x,0)$ is contained in a neighbourhood $N\subseteq U$ because of the open property of $U$ but I don't know how to go whittle that down to the conclusion as $N$ is a neighbourhood in product space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=\langle x,0\rangle$. You know that there is an open $V$ in $\Bbb R^2$ such that $U=V\cap A$: that’s just the definition of the subspace topology on $A$. You also know that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(p,\epsilon)\subseteq V$, where $B(p,\epsilon)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centred at $p$. Thus,

$$B(p,\epsilon)\cap A\subseteq V\cap A=U\,.$$

Next, it’s clear that

$$(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\times\{0\}\subseteq B(p,\epsilon)\,.$$

Finally,

$$(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\times\{0\}\subseteq\Bbb R\times\{0\}\subseteq A\,,$$

so

$$(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\times\{0\}\subseteq B(p,\epsilon)\cap A\subseteq U\,.$$

Comment: Is the statement in the 2nd line because the topology on the product space is induced by a metric and so the collection of open balls is a basis?

Comment: @Jaunemoto: We’re dealing with the usual topology on $\Bbb R^2$, which is both the product topology and the topology defined by the usual Euclidean metric, so yes, the open balls are a base for it. So are the open boxes, so we could instead observe that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq V$ and use that in exactly the same way that I used $B(p,\epsilon)$.

Comment: @Jaunemoto: We can, since it generates the right topology. This isn’t really a metric space problem: all that matters here is the topology, and in the absence of a statement or clear context to the contrary, we always assume that the topology on $\Bbb R^2$ is the usual one.

Comment: Is the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ the same as the usual one?

Comment: @Jaunemoto: Yes: the box topology on any product with a **finite** number of factors is the same as the usual product topology.

Comment: I'm aware of that result but I meant more how do we know the box/product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the one inherited from the usual metric?

Comment: @Jaunemoto: It has to be proved, but it’s a standard result.